# Spring beans are loaded twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Springboot application that is getting deployed to Tomcat server. During the server start up I see beans are getting loaded twice. Please find my main class below and server start up log as well. Could you please suggest about how to avoid loading the beans twice?

Point to note is that I am deploying the code as a WAR file on tomcat server

Environment is Springboot, Tomcat server, Jdk11

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(EntryExitApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Application start up log

```
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.TestApplication - Starting TestApplication v2022.12.20-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.18 on L9 with PID 20656 (C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.71-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\webapps\test_web_war\WEB-INF\classes started by TEST in C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.71-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin)
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.TestApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 114 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4954 ms
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'mutuallyExclusiveList' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'mutuallyExclusiveGroup' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'miSelectionProcess' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'miTokenCache' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'sVendorInfo' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.ParameterFactory - Loading properties from System properties
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.ParameterFactory - Loaded environment variable from System properties: TEST
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.ParameterFactory - Environment variable reset to from system property: TEST
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - mConnectionPool - Starting...
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - mConnectionPool - Start completed.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'dummyScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'dummyScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@693c7d3
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler dummyScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.



[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@4c13e43b
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver - Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.TestApplication - Started EntryExitApplication in 14.766 seconds (JVM running for 32.308)
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.ParameterFactory - Loading properties from System properties
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.ParameterFactory - Loaded environment variable from System properties: TEST
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.abc.entry.ParameterFactory - Environment variable reset to from system property: TEST
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'mutuallyExclusiveList' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'mutuallyExclusiveGroup' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'miSelectionProcess' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'miTokenCache' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'sVendorInfo' created in EhcacheManager.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - mConnectionPool - Starting...
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - mConnectionPool - Start completed.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'dummyScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Comment: Hey possible to remove @PropertySource and try it again?

Comment: no luck even after removing the annotation

Comment: would you mind sharing project structure?